# How can I concatenate attributes together

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sandbox.xsl"?>
<root>
  <base PV="a">
    <element1 PV="b">
      <Item PV="c" />
    </element1>
    <element2 PV="d">
      <element3 PV="e">
        <Item PV="f" />
      </element3>
    </element2>
  </base>
</root>
```

Now i am trying to concatenate a PV name of an Item with all PV names of the parent elements and this recursiv.

For example for the Element Item with the PV name c I wanna get:
`a.b.c`, and for the Item f I wanna get `a.d.e.f`

I have tried with

```
<table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../@PV"/>.
        <xsl:value-of select="../../@PV"/>.
        <xsl:value-of select="../@PV"/>.
      <xsl:value-of select="@PV"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

With te result

```
. a. b. c
a. d. e. f
```

The problem is, that i do not know how many "parent" elements I have in my XML.

Then i have tried with

```
<xsl:variable name="curr" select="//Item[@PV = 'f']"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="test" select="$curr/ancestor-or-self::*[@PV]"></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="$test">
    <xsl:value-of select="@PV"></xsl:value-of>.
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Here i get the correct answer but only for the Item f and with some spaces inside, which i do not want `a. d. e. f.`

How can i create a list for al Items?

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*/@PV" separator="."/>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 1.0 this needs to be expressed as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*/@PV">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">.</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am using XSLT 1.0 and it is working!